# Bounds on error term in prime number theorem directly from exponential sum estimates

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Most improvements on the zero-free region for $\zeta(s)$ go through bounds on the exponential sums $$\sum_{n\sim N} n^{it}$$
for $N$ in certain ranges depending on $|t|$. Is there any way to directly show the prime number theorem from such exponential sum bounds (with the improved error terms the resulting zero-free regions yield), without going through $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "avoiding zeta." Zeta is closely connected to the exponential sums above (by partial summation), so it would be hard not to mention it. What I think is closest in spirit to what you are looking for is the "pretentious" approach. See, e.g., the proof of the PNT via Halasz's theorem in https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/Book.To2.5.pdf, or how bounds for $\sum (n+u)^{it}$ are utilized in Koukoulopoulos' "Pretentious multiplicative functions and the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions" (which uses Dirichlet series only in their domain of convergence).

Comment: (Since you mentioned "improved error terms," it is worth noting that by using bounds for those exponential sums, the latter paper proves the PNT for APs in the same strength achieved by the Vinogradov--Korobov zero-free region.)

Answer (score 1):

There is not a commonly agreed definition on "without going through $\zeta(s)$," but it is possible to wrap up all the $\zeta$ processes between the exponential sum and the remainder of the PNT.

According to Titchmarsh's *The theory of the Riemann zeta function*, it is not difficult to convert growth condition of $\zeta(s)$ into a zero-free region:

**Lemma A (see §3.10 of Titchmarsh):** Let $\phi(t)$ and $1/\theta(t)$ be positive nondecreasing functions defined on $t\ge0$ such that

- $\zeta(s)\ll\exp\phi(t)$ in $1-\theta(t)\le\sigma\le2$ and $s=\sigma+it$
- $\theta(t)\le1$
- $\phi(t)\to+\infty$ as $t\to+\infty$
- $\phi(t)/\theta(t)=o(\exp\phi(t))$

Then there is a constant $c_0>0$ such that $\zeta(s)$ is free of zeros whenever

$$
\sigma\ge1-c_0{\theta(2|t|+1)\over\phi(2|t|+1)}
$$

To convert the zero-free region into the remainder of the PNT, we may consider the explicit formula provided by Montgomery & Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I: Classical Theory*:

**Lemma B (see §12.1 of Montgomery & Vaughan):** For $T\le x$ and $\psi(x)=\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)$, we have

$$
\psi(x)=x-\sum_{|\Im\rho|\le T}{x^\rho\over\rho}+\mathcal O\left(x\log x\over T\right)
$$

where $\rho$ denotes the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$.

Under Lemma B, we see that to obtain remainder for the PNT, all we need is to estimate the sum over nontrivial zeros. For convenience, we write

$$
\Theta_T=1-c_0{\theta(2T+1)\over\phi(2T+1)}
$$

Then we have

$$
\left|\sum_{|\Im\rho|\le T}{x^\rho\over\rho}\right|\le x^{\Theta_T}\sum_{|\Im\rho|\le T}{1\over|\Im\rho|}
$$

To estimate the reciprocal sum, we quote Riemann-von Mangoldt formula:

**Lemma C (see §9.4 of Titchmarsh):** Let $N(T)$ denote the number of nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ with imaginary parts lying between zero and $T$, then

$$
N(T)={T\over2\pi}\log{T\over2\pi}-\log{T\over2\pi}+\mathcal O(\log T)
$$

This indicates that

$$
\sum_{|\Im\rho|\le T}{1\over|\Im\rho|}=2\int_0^T{\mathrm dN(u)\over u}\ll(\log T)^2
$$

Plugging these results into Lemma B, we get

**Theorem (relationship between $\zeta(s)$'s growth condition and the remainder of the PNT):** Let $\theta(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ be functions satisfying the conditions of Lemma A. Then there exists a constant $c_0>0$ such that for any $T\le x$, we have

$$
\psi(x)=x+\mathcal O\left\{x(\log x)^2\exp\left(-{c_0\theta(2T+1)\log x\over\phi(2T+1)}\right)+{x\log x\over T}\right\}
$$